# How to find domain of definition of solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the given initial-value problem:
$$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{\left(y+2\right)^{2}}, \quad y(0)=1$$
we are asked to solve it then to state the domain of definition of the solution. So first of all I separated the variables and applied the initial condition and obtained:
$$y(t)=\left(3t+27\right)^{1/3}-2$$

but now I can't figure out why does the solution exist only when $t>-9$? I am having trouble understanding also what does this have to do with $\dfrac{dy}{dt}$ not being defined at $y=-2$. Why are we letting
$$3t+27 >0 $$

what if $t=-10$? how does this make $y$ undefined?

Comment: Mathematically you're right, the function $y(t) = \left(3t + 27\right)^{1/3} - 2$ with the caveat that $t \neq -9$ satisfies both the differential equation and the given initial condition. The only objection I can think of to disallow $t \lt -9$ is that in any physical system time is continuous, and the initial condition is on one branch, so there is no way to "hop" to the other branch. But that is a physics limitation rather than a math limitation.

Comment: @MatthewvanEerde That makes sense if the general solution consists of two separate (discontinuous) branches. That's not the case here. The only issue here is that for $t=-9$ the solution-curve is not differentiable. That's the only (perhaps peculiar?) reason for the restricted domain, otherwise I wouldn't know

Comment: The physical limitation comes not from having to do a "jump" in displacement, but in having to pass from moving infinitely quickly in one direction to moving infinitely quickly in the other direction.

Comment: That's true, after all, $dy/dt$ does not exist for t=-9

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{1}{\left(y+2\right)^{2}}$$
$$t=\int (y+2)^2dy=\frac13 (y+2)^3 +c$$
Condition : $t(1)=0=\frac13 (1+2)^3 +c \quad\implies\quad c=-9 $
$$t=\frac13 (y+2)^3-9$$
For $y$ and $t$ reals this implies $t>-9$.

[image]

If the problem is from Physic the speed $y'(t)$ is infinite at $(t=-9\:,\:y=-2)$ .  This excludes the branch $y\leq -2$.

Answer (score 0):

It is perhaps not stated often enough outright, but in standard ODE theory, where the "O" stands for "ordinary", the domain of the ODE is supposed to be an open set that is chosen so that the right side exists, and is continuous in all variables. A solution is then a continuously differentiable function with a graph inside that set.

In this case this means that the line $y=-2$ is a boundary of the domain, and as the initial condition is $y(0)=1$, the domain is the upper part $\{(x,y):y>-2\}$. As you computed, the solution only stays inside this domain for $t>-9$. There can be no more solution in the given context.

Now it is of course quite possible to consider limits of the solution at the boundary, and solutions in the second domain $\{(x,y):y<-2\}$, pairs of solutions that can be joined together at the boundary, or result from the same algebraic expression. But these are extended solution concepts, which need to be requested explicitly.